# Пайтон не видит в регулярке симовол " ' "

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер

```
name_films = re.findall(r"<a class=\"films_name ref\" href=\"\/movies\/[\d]+\/\">([**'**a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ «»\"+\d№=.\(\)\-+,?!^:;]+)<\/a>",self.req.text)
```

Нужно взять Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра

```html
<a class="films_name ref" href="/movies/7731575/">Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра</a>
```

Я не понимаю почему. Подскажите пж(
В regex101 берет, а в проге нет

Comment: Эта тема поднималась уже не раз, не нужно xml/html парсинг регулярками. Если парсить, то очень осторожно и как можно проще, т.к. разобраться после в чем-то типа `([**'**a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ «»\"+\d№=.\(\)\-+,?!^:;]+)` может оказаться сложно и проще будет переписать. Еще мне непонятно для чего вы экранируете кавычки в raw-строках. У вас ведь там будет не один символ -- кавычка, а два \ и ", и если в строке не будет \ и идущего за него ", то это не должно сматчиться. Если у вас сразу несколько кавычек, используйте тройные `"""` или `'''`, тогда не нужно экранировать обычные кавычки

Comment: Кст, скопировал ваш код и текст, и у меня нашлось регуляркой: `["Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра"]`

Answer (score 3):

У меня ваш код работает без ошибок.

Кроме того, регулярку можно немного упростить:

```
import re

text = """
<a class="films_name ref" href="/movies/7731575/">Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра</a>
<a class="films_name ref" href="/movies/7731575/">Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра</a>
"""

name_films = re.findall("""<a class="films_name ref" href="/movies/\d+/">(.+?)</a>""", text)
print(name_films)
# ["Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра", "Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра"]
```

---

Но я бы рекомендовал **парсить парсерами**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
print([a.text for a in root.select('.films_name')])
# ["Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра", "Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра"]
```

Объясняю на примере, в той `html` могут вместо кавычек использоваться одинарные, атрибуты могут поменяться местами, добавиться новые атрибуты или новые значения в атрибуты, например в `class`:

```
text = """
<a class="films_name ref" href="/movies/7731575/">Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра</a>
<a href='/movies/7731575/' class='ref films_name favorite' style="">Д'Артаньян и три мушкетёра</a>
"""
```

Парсер отработает также, а регулярка уже нет. Т.к. она ожидает регулярные выражения, а html/xml не регулярные